# How to read previous XmlReader element

Tags: xml, xmlwriter, xmltextreader

I've been working on a project where I need to get some information of a XML document, and insert on another XML document, but they are different files, and the new file must not exceed 400KB, and I'm trying to return the Read() method go back to the last element he readed, and to remove the element of XmlWriter().
Any ideas?

Comment: How large is the input file? If it fits in memory, then try reading the whole thing in with `XDocument`, then writing out chunks at a time until you get near 400KB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `XmlReader` is a forward-only reader of nodes, and `XmlWriter` is a forward-only writer.

Comment: Ok, that was helpfull. But, do you know a way to do that?